# Get author meta data with no published posts in author.php?

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, loop

Unfortunately the following codes **only echo** the spcefic default and custom author datas if the author has at least **one** published post :(

```
<?php the_author_meta('description'); ?>

<?php the_author_posts(); ?>

<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Twitter Pro'), get_the_author() ); ?>
```

Is it **possible** to retrieve the authors meta data in **author.php** when the author has published 0 posts?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that try using;

```
<?php get_userdata( $userid ); ?>
```

For example;

```
<?php 
  $user_info = get_userdata(1);    // get info for user id '1'
  $username = $user_info->user_login;
  $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
  $last_name = $user_info->last_name;
?>
```

For more details visit [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata).

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Comment: Thanks kaiser for pointing me in the right direction. just edit my answer.